# JGoodies Binding: How to bind two ValueModels?

Tags: java, swing, binding, jgoodies

The simplified case is
I have

```
ValueHolder a = new ValueHolder();

ValueHolder b = new ValueHolder();
```

I am looking for

```
[some JGoodies Class].[method](a,b);
```

That will connect those `ValueModel`s and keep them mutually updated

I can not find among all static classes like `PropertyConnector`, `Bindings`, `ObjectBinder` etc do not have a method to connect two ValueModels

I am sure I am missing something.

My actual use case a little bit more complicated as I am building a reusable component that has calculated `ValueModel` and I need for a code that will use it to pass a `ValueModel` that will be bonded to it so the user will be able to do other complicated things with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way

```
PropertyConnector.connect(valueModelA, "value", valueModelB, "value");
```